# Associative containers, is the comparison function not part of element type?

Tags: c++, templates

I think, the comparsion function, which can passed to the template of an associative container, like `std::set` or `std::multiset`, is not part of the actual `element type` of the instantiated container-type?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include "Sales_data_ex1119.hpp"
using namespace std;

bool compare_isbn(const Sales_data& lhs, const Sales_data& rhs) {
    return lhs.isbn() < rhs.isbn();
}

int main() {
    using cmp_func = bool (*)(const Sales_data& lhs, const Sales_data& rhs);
    multiset<Sales_data, cmp_func> bookstore(&compare_isbn);
    Sales_data foo("978", 2, 22.22);
    Sales_data foo2("978", 2, 22.22);
    Sales_data bar("979", 3, 22.22);
    Sales_data baz("980", 2, 22.22);

    bookstore.insert(foo);
    bookstore.insert(foo2);
    bookstore.insert(bar);
    bookstore.insert(baz);

    // comparsion function is not part of element type?
    multiset<Sales_data>::iterator it = bookstore.begin();
    while (it != bookstore.end()) {
        print(cout, *it++);
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    // but the comparsion function can be applied also
    multiset<Sales_data, cmp_func>::iterator it2 = bookstore.begin();
    while (it2 != bookstore.end()) {
        print(cout, *it2++);
        cout << "\n";
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Both definitions, `it` and `it2` compile and run fine with GCC 7. It makes sense to me, the `key_type` is defined as `Sales_data` and the `key_type` for `std::set` and `std::multiset` is the `element type`.
If seen a lot of [people](https://github.com/chihyang/CPP_Primer/blob/master/chap11/Exer11_19.cpp) [using](https://github.com/jaege/Cpp-Primer-5th-Exercises/blob/master/ch11/11.19.md) the comparsion function in the definition, which is probably just more explixit but not necessary.

Thanks

Comment: But you cannot do this, `multiset<Sales_data> newstore = bookstore;` So the comparison function is definitely part of the type. I change iterator line to `set<Sales_data>::iterator it = bookstore.begin();`, and the program compiles and runs the same.

Comment: You're right.  error: conversion from ‘std::multiset<Sales_data, bool (*)(const Sales_data&, const Sales_data&)>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::multiset<Sales_data>’ requested*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think, the comparsion function, which can passed to the template of an associative container, like std::set or std::multiset, is not part of the actual element type of the instantiated container-type?

The only totally-dependable type for an iterator into a `multiset<Key,Compare,Allocator>` is `multiset<Key,Compare,Allocator>::iterator`.

Now, because each node in the multiset doesn't *really* need either the sort order or the allocator to do its job, and because library writers prefer to avoid duplication, there's a very good chance that there's a single iterator class template somewhere in your standard library, which is shared between all the (multi)(set|map) classes, and which depends only on the element type.

But if this is the case, it's an implementation detail, is non-portable and is subject to change. So, this:

```
multiset<Sales_data, cmp_func> bookstore(&compare_isbn);
multiset<Sales_data>::iterator it = bookstore.begin();
```

may well work, for now. But it would be entirely legitimate for another compiler or library implementation to refuse it.

Anyway, even without including the Compare (and Allocator!) type parameters, writing out the whole thing is pretty tedious. Just use

```
auto it = bookstore.begin()
```

and forget about the whole thing. Or, better still:

```
for (auto &sale : bookstore) {
```

or in your particular case, write the stream insertion operator and use

```
copy(begin(bookstore), end(bookstore),
     ostream_iterator<Sales_data>(cout, "\n"));
```